# how to improve corner detection accuracy

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I used chessboard corner detection algorithm for my research.I used goodFeaturesToTrack to find the corners and cvFindCornerSubPix used to refine that corners in subpixel level.
In my first trail ,fixed a chessboard in front of camera and took nearly 5 images.After finding subpixel level i found corners For first image like this.

> (x,y) = (1259.422974,784.823181) (x,y) = (1258.550537,828.983459)
>   (x,y) = (1257.704956,873.095154) (x,y) = (1256.886188,917.151306)

For second image my corners are like this

> (x,y) = (1259.426147,784.866272) (x,y) = (1258.548584,829.007916)
>   (x,y) = (1257.697754,873.099915) (x,y) = (1256.873779,917.136719)

i used deadreg  as given below

```
cornerCriter.epsilon = 0.0005;
cornerCriter.max_iter = 30;
cornerCriter.type = 3;
winSize.height = 30;
winSize.width = 30;
deadReg.height = -1;
deadReg.width = -1;
```

i used 10MP camera and my chessboard square size is 40mm each.My problem is i got the accuracy of corners are 0.1 pixel.But i required 0.001 pixel accuracy. is there any way to archive this accuracy?is corners are noise dependent?does any noise will present when camera capturing images?
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

0.001 = 1/1000th of a pixel in accuracy does not seem realistic at all. 0.1 is actually already quite reasonable.

You have litle room for improvement here, so you'd better use some posterior stages in your pipeline that require less accuracy (use robust estimators, etc.).

Comment: Thanks sansuiso..Sorry if i am wrong...i need to maintain the subpixel in all the images equally...i d'not know where it need any interpolation methods to maintain the accuracy... can you tell me how can i maintain all corners are equal for all images.